# Shorter way to change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in Debian-Nginx environments

Tags: php, nginx, sed, automation, debian

I know two ways to change `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` files in Debian-Nginx environments (I personally use Ubuntu as a Debian env):

**1)** Manual change.

**2)** Sed operation:

```
sed -i "s/post_max_size = .M/post_max_size = 250M/ ; s/upload_max_filesize = .M/upload_max_filesize = 250M/" /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
```

Is there a shorter way to change these in Deiban-Nginx environments (to `>=250M`)?

Answer (score 0):

## Shorter version

```
 sed 's/\(\(post_max_size\|upload_max_filesize\) = \).M/\1250M/g' /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
```

1) `\(post_max_size\|upload_max_filesize\)` regexp for  post_max_size or upload_max_filesize

2) `sed 's///g'` ru changes on the all file

3) `\1` value in the outside Parenthesis (concatenation of \1 and 250 M )

4) if you want to change original files use `sed -i`